# Give an example visual recognition task where a fully connected network would be more suitable than a convolution neural networks

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, image-recognition

I know CNN has a lot of good features like weight sharing, save memory and feature extracting. However, this question makes me very confused. Is there any possible situation that fully connected network better than CNN? Why?

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any possible situation that fully connected network better than CNN?

Well, I think we should first define what we mean by "better". Accuracy and precision are not the only things to consider: computational time, degrees of freedom and difficulty of the optimization should also be taken into account.

First, consider an input of size `h*w*c`. Feeding this input to a convolutional layer with `F` featuremaps and kernel size `s` will result in at about `F*s*s*c` learnable parameters (assuming there are no constraints on the ranks of the convolutions, otherwise we even have less parameters.). Feeding the same input into a fully connected layer with the same number of featuremaps will result in `F*d_1*d_2*w*h*c`, (where `d_1,d_2` are the dimensions of each featuremap) which is clearly in the order of billions of learnable parameters given any input image with decent resolution.

While it can be tempting to think that we can get away with shallower networks (we already have lots of parameters, right?), fully connected layers are just linear layers after all, so we still need to insert many non-linearities in order for the network to gain reasonable representational power. So, this will mean that you will still need a deep network, however with so many parameters that it would be untractable. In addition, a larger network will have more degrees of freedom, and will therefore model much more than what we want: it will model noise unless we feed it some data or constrain it.

So yes, there might be a fully connected network that in theory could give us better performance, but we don't know how to train it yet. Finally, and this is purely based on intuition and therefore might be wrong, but it seems unlikely to me that such a fully connected network would converge to a dense solution. Since many convolutional networks achieve very high levels of accuracy (99% and up) on many tasks, I think that the optimal solution the fully connected network would converge to would be close to the convolutional network. So, we don't really need to train the fully connected one, but just a subset of its architecture.